# Protractor : E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Am facing 'Unable to start a WebDriver session' when trying to execute protractor tests through chrome.After trying out all the below options, am posting here for a solution :

1. Triggered the run with latest and earlier versions of chrome browser and driver
2. Manually placed chromedriver in webdriver-manager/selenium path.

3.added chromeOptions: {
binary: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"}

Please let me know how to resolve this issue .Current O.S is Catalina : 10.15.7.

Below is the error :

$ protractor config.js

[13:26:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:26:19] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[13:26:19] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.4:53615/wd/hub
[13:26:40] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[13:26:40] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: add your config content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after removing node modules, uninstalling protractor , npm and reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 0):

update webdriver by using following in terminal:

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```